# Displaying JSON result in table using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I am trying to display a JSON output from my AJAX script as a result of a search done from a form.  Currently, I can successfully display the JSON output within a DIV.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#searchForm').submit(function(){
            // show that something is loading
            $('#loadingmessage').show();  // show the loading message.
            $('#response').html("<b>Loading response...</b>");
            $('#searchResults').hide();

            /*
             * 'post_receiver.php' - where you will pass the form data
             * $(this).serialize() - to easily read form data
             * function(data){... - data contains the response from post_receiver.php
             */
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'php/quicksearch.php', 
                data: $(this).serialize()
            })
            .done(function(data){
                // show the response
                $('#loadingmessage').hide();  // show the loading message.
                $('#searchDiv').show();
                $('#searchResults').show();
                $('#searchResults').html(data);
                $("#searchForm")[0].reset();
                //alert(data);
            })
            .fail(function() {
                // just in case posting your form failed
                alert( "Search failed." );
            });
            // to prevent refreshing the whole page page
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

My HTML code :

```
<div id = "searchDiv">
    <div id='loadingmessage' style='display:none'>
        <img src='ajax-loader.gif'/>
    </div>
    <div id="searchResults"> </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone please help me with how I can display the JSON data returned from my PHP script into a bootstrap table? The JSON contains a large number of columns so I don't want to have to break down thru each column in the javascript instead just pass the JSON directly to the bootstrap table.

If no results are found from my search form I already handle this with a response " no search found" back to the page otherwise a JSON output is created if a search match is found.

Comment: The table does not know how to display your JSON data. You will have to pass appropriate values to the table column for it to display correctly

Comment: okay, then how do i do it the manual way and display the JSON records in a bootstrap table

Comment: If you are using bootstrap table library, refer http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/getting-started/